Implementing HMS Push Notifications & Firebase at the same time
Problem
Currently I have done developing my mobile apps to be workable in IOS and Android but now I want to make it to be supported for Huawei Harmony OS as well. Right now after downloaded the .apk file it show black screen because because it uses firebase cloud messaging which prohibited by Harmony OS.
My Solution
Currently, I plan to implement firebase and HMS at the same time by checking the HMS availability with the solution below following this link . Will my apps able to be supported in Harmony OS if I called the firebase package but prevent using the code from using any firebase package functions? Is my way correct or I should change to use HMS push notifications only or there is any other solutions that I could use?
Note:
Currently, I am still waiting Developer Account to be approved so I still can't test yet.
Firebase Package Used:
firebase_core: ^2.24.0
firebase_messaging: ^14.7.6

My Solutions
Future<int> checkHMSAvailability() async {
    HmsApiAvailability client = HmsApiAvailability();
    
    // Check HMS Core (APK) availability status
    int status = await client.isHMSAvailable();

    return status;
}

//When Initializing 
int status = await checkHMSAvailability();
if (status == 1){
    FirebaseAPI().initNotifications();
} else {
    //HMS Notifications Setup Code Here
}


You'd need DevEco Studio in order to build HAP (application package) for HarmonyOS.
Else you could only build for Android OS, with Google and Huawei implementations.
This also requires a backend, which can interact with Apple, Google, Huawei API.
For example: Have both GMS and HMS in the project.
